# Do New_to_publish hooks work for custom post types

Tags: hooks

Do these hooks listed on the following site work for custom post types?

http://www.wphub.com/custom-post-type-publish-action-hook/

```
    // function to be executed when a custom post type is published
    function run_when_post_published()
    {
        // your function code here
    }

    // replace {custom_post_type_name} with the name of your post type
    add_action('new_to_publish_{custom_post_type_name}', 'run_when_post_published');        
    add_action('draft_to_publish_{custom_post_type_name}', 'run_when_post_published');      
    add_action('pending_to_publish_{custom_post_type_name}', 'run_when_post_published');
```

I cannot get them to work...

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Show some code, please.

Comment: Please formulate your question in a meaningful and complete way, rather than sending people elsewhere to try and figure out what you mean.

Comment: updated question, that's the code I'm trying out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using wrong hooks. Please take a look at [wp_transition_post_status](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L3125) function, you'll see the correct hooks:

```
function wp_transition_post_status($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    do_action('transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post);
    do_action("{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}", $post);
    do_action("{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post);
}
```

So, in your code, you should use hooks:

```
'new_to_publish'   
'draft_to_publish'
'pending_to_publish'
```

and in your function, you have to **check your post type**.

Comment: How do I check my post type correctly?

Comment: I had changed my code in the meantime to use: add_action('publish_myt_cpt', 'myfunction');

The issue I have now is that myfunction() needs the ID of the latest inserted post, and it isn't finding it. So I am thinking that the hook is running before the post is published, making my function not produce the desired result. Is this so?

Comment: I also don't understand why to use the hooks you mentioned then check the post type within the function, when I can directly use an action which would fire only for the desired post type, making that check within the function redundant.

Comment: The other thing is that my function needs to be called from various places, even from cron for example, so that check for post type within the function would mess up things for me. It would be much better to have a hook that fires specifically when a defined custom post type is published.